# How to find asymptotes

Tags: asymptotics

I'm supposed to find asymptotes for $x\cdot\arctan(x)$ for a homework assignment.

Are there any theorems regarding this I can utilize to find the equation for the asymptotes, or is this one of those solve case by case things, where this particular equation can be solved in some neat way, but there is no easy universal way to find asymptotes like this?

I know it should be:

$$\pm \frac{\pi}{2} x - 1$$

but "how do I show this?" is essentially my question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean $1/\tan(x)$ or $\arctan(x)$ multiplied by $x$?

Comment: arctan, didn't think about the confusion it might lead to not specify :)

Comment: $x \cdot \arctan(x)$ doesn't have any asymptotes.

Comment: Well yes it does. Look here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=asymptote+x+atan%28x%29 Same goes for the other side as well, even though WA does not show it.

Comment: @AndreasHagen Sorry, that's my stupid misunderstanding. I'm too used to thinking of asymptotes as horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure the following is in your textbook and/or has been explained in class.

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function.

1. If $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=a$, then $y=a$ is a *horizontal* asymptote (similarly for $x\to-\infty$.)
2. If for some $b\in\mathbb{R}$ $\lim_{x\to b^+}f(x)=\pm\infty$, then $x=b$ is a *vertical* asymptote (similarly for $x\to b^-$.)
3. If $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=m$, $m\ne0$, and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}(f(x)-m\,x)=c$, then $y=m\,x+c$ is an *oblique* asymptote similarly for $x\to-\infty$.)

Apply it to $x\arctan x$. The only difficulty is finding $\lim_{x\to-\infty}x\,(\arctan x-\frac\pi2)$, which can be done using L'Hôpital's rule.