How to find the asymptotes of $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$?
The task is to find all the asymptotes (horizontal, vertical, or whatever) of
$$
f(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}.
$$
Obviously, there are vertical asymptotes at $x=2$ and $x=-2$.
Next, how can I find out whether there are other asymptotes, say, as $x\to\pm\infty$?
The plot seems to suggest $y=x$ and $y=-x$ are asymptotes. But I do not see how to get these without looking at the plot.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221494/1135547

To compute the horizontal asymptotes evaluate $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x)$; to compute the oblique asymptotes not that $\sqrt{x^2-4}\sim \sqrt {x^2}=|x|$

Do you mean $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}\sim\frac{x^2}{\vert x\vert}=\begin{cases}x, & \textrm{ as } x\to\infty\-x, & \textrm{ as }x\to -\infty\end{cases}$

@selector I strongly recommend that you have a look at the link I shared in my first comment.

You could easily find if the curve is above or below the oblique asymptotes.

As a general method, giving that $g(x)=px+q$ is an asymptote, since $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\frac{g(x)}x = p $, we need that (necessary condition) a such finite limit exists also for $f$ that is
$$\lim_{x\to  \pm \infty}\frac{f(x)}x =\lim_{x\to  \pm \infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} = \pm1$$
then, to show that asymptote exist, since $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}g(x)-px = q$, we also need to check that such finite limits exist also for $f$ that is
$$\lim_{x\to   \infty}f(x) - x=\lim_{x\to   \infty}\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{x^2-4}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} =\lim_{x\to   \infty}\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{x^2-4}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}  \frac{x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-4}}=$$
$$=\lim_{x\to   \infty}\frac{4x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}(x^2+x\sqrt{x^2-4})}=\lim_{x\to   \infty}\frac{4}{\sqrt{1-4/x^2}(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})}=0$$
and then also
$$\lim_{x\to   -\infty}f(x) + x=\lim_{x\to   \infty}f(-x) - x=\lim_{x\to   \infty}f(x) - x=0$$
therefore $y=\pm x$ are asymptotes for $f$.

How did you get rid of the $x$? I only get
$$
\lim_{x\to   \infty}f(x) - x=\lim_{x\to   \infty}\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{x^2-4}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} =\lim_{x\to   \infty}\frac{x\cdot (1-\sqrt{1-4/{x^2}})}{\sqrt{1-4/{x^2}}}
$$

Why? Sorry, but I get (for $x>2$)
$$
\frac{x^2-x\sqrt{x^2-4}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}=\frac{x^2-x^2\sqrt{1-4/x^2}}{x\sqrt{1-4/x^2}}=\frac{x^2(1-\sqrt{1-4/x^2})}{x\sqrt{1-4/x^2}}=\frac{x(1-\sqrt{1-4/x^2})}{\sqrt{1-4/x^2}}
$$

@selector I've fixed it! Sorry but I've solved them mentally without recognize the mistake at first! Bye

No HA, because $$\lim_{x\to - \infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} = \lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} = +\infty$$ are not finite!
VA: $x=\pm2$ because
$$\lim_{x\to(\pm2)^{\pm}}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}=+\infty
$$
where limits are performed in the domain of the function $(-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)$.
OA: $$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}-ax-b=0$$
gives $b=0$ and $a=1$ at $\infty$; $a=-1$ at $-\infty.$
Proof: Recall the Maclaurin series
$$\sqrt{1-t}=1-\frac12 t-\frac18 t^2+...$$
$$\frac1{1-t}=1+t+t^2+...$$
Using these series, for some $N$ and $|x|>N$, we have
$$\operatorname{sgn}(x)x<\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}<\operatorname{sgn}(x)x+\frac{\color{red}{3}\operatorname{sgn}(x)}x.$$
Now, by squeeze theorem we can conclude.

Why do we know that oblique asymptotes, if any, are lines, i.e. of the form $y=ax+b$?

@selector Do you mean that  they can be quadratic?

Thinking of rational functions, they can be any polynomial in general. Why not here?

Could you please explain why $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-ax-b)=0$ implies $a=1$ and $b=0$ and why $\lim_{x\to -\infty}(f(x)-ax-b)=0$ implies $a=-1$ and $b=0$?

Because $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}\approx \operatorname{sgn}(x)x$ at infinities. @selector

@BobDobbs you can't say that there are vertical asymptotes where the denominator is null. You must evaluate the limit of the complete function. For example $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ does not have a vertical asymptote at zero. Also, the first limits exist, you should say that they are not finite

@DavideMasi Evaluations give $+\infty$

@BobDobbs I am only referring to what you wrote. I mean, if the OP doesn't know how to find the asymptotes your answer will probably give them wrong ideas

The domain should be mentioned, as some problem could be: $$\frac{x^2(x-2)}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2-4}}$$ These problems can get very tricky for students.

I'm not clear on whether the OP is convinced about the oblique asymptotes, so maybe this will help.
Note that for $x>2$,
$$x-\sqrt{x^2-4} =\frac{(x-\sqrt{x^2-4})(x+\sqrt{x^2-4} )}{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}
 =\frac{x^2-(x^2-4)}{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}}=\frac{4}{x+\sqrt{x^2-4}},$$ which converges to $0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty $.
Next, observe that for sufficiently large $x$ (say $x>3$),
$$\Big{|} \frac{x^2 }{\sqrt{x^2-4} }-x\Big{|} = |x|\Big{|} \frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-4}}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}\Big{|}=\Big{|}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-4}} \Big{|} |x-\sqrt{x^2-4}|\leq 2|x-\sqrt{x^2-4}|.$$ It follows by the squeeze theorem that $y=x$ is an oblique asmptote. A similar argument will work for $y=-x$.

If you only consider the highest degrees terms, you find that in the neighbourhood of $\pm\infty$ we have $f(x)\approx \frac x {\sqrt{x^2}}$. Thus we have asymptotic directions of $+1$ near $+\infty$ and $-1$ near $-\infty$.
Let us look more precisely what happens in the neighbourhood of $+\infty$ ($x > 2$):
$$\begin{align*}f(x)-x &= \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}-x = \frac x {\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}}-x=x\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}}\\
&= x\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\right)}\\
&=x\frac{1-\left(1-\frac 4{x^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\right)}=x\frac{\frac 4{x^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\right)}\\
&=\frac 1 x\times\frac 4{\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\right)}
\end{align*}$$
As we have trivially $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}{\frac 1 x}=0$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}{\frac 4{\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}\right)}}=2$, we can conclude that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}{\left(f(x) - x\right)}=0$.
That means that the line defined by $y=x$ is an oblique asymptote at $+\infty$.
Near $-\infty$, we can write (for $x<-2$):
$$\begin{align*}f(x)+x &= \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}+x = \frac {-x} {\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}}+x=x\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-\frac 4{x^2}}}\\
\end{align*}$$
Using the same method as above, we could show that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}{\left(f(x) + x\right)}=0$, which means that the line defined by $y=-x$ is an oblique asymptote at $-\infty$.
